# Object Not Persisting in CouchDB

Tags: ruby, sinatra, couchdb, couchrest

I am trying to store my ruby object in couchdb with couchrest. I am extending my model from `CouchRest::Model::Base` But still i am unable to see the changes in db.

I've defined Server as CouchRest.new also mentioned in model to `use_database 'players'`

```
# Controller Method
get '/new/:name' do 
    DB = SERVER.database!('players')
    @new_player = Player.new(params['name'])
    @new_player.create
    "success: #{@new_player.persisted?}" #shows true

# Model
class Player < CouchRest::Model::Base
    use_database 'players'
    property :name ,String
    timestamps!

    def initialize(arg)
        @name=arg
    end
end
```

- How To Persist the object?
- How can i retreive all persisted objects?
- Is there any simple applications which i can refer to?

Comment: can you please paste the code for Player?

Comment: furthermore, it seems you are using this in a Sinatra app. I am not quite sure but the purpose of couch_rest_model is for the usage in Rails. So you need at least ActiveModel included ...

Comment: so if i want to use couchdb in sinatra, whats the best way to use it? I thought couchrest simplifies the process

Comment: I haven't used CouchRest::Model, just CouchRest. One thing that may help is to turn on logging for RestClient (which CouchRest uses). Then you see exactly what is being sent to CouchDB:
    RestClient.log = 'stderr'

Comment: I have used couch_potato - I think it is built on top of CouchRest to get ORM-ish behavior.